# Adding Records to multiple tables with a button

Tags: ms-access, vba, many-to-many, addition

I created a button on a form to add to multiple tables. So I have a many-to-many relationship with the following tables:

- tblComputer(Computer)
- tblHDD(HDD)
- tblComputer-HDD(Computer, HDD)

On the form, I have two textboxes: txtComputer and txtHDD. When I click the button, the record would be added into all of the tables. If the record exist for either tblComputer or tblHDD, then it will only add it into tblComputer-HDD. Any help would be great! I also provided the database in the following link:

[Add Item database](https://onedrive.live.com/redir?resid=558CDD62356141AF!6915&authkey=!ADa9Sz6fn5Wc2Xk&ithint=file%2Caccdb)

Here is my vba code as well:

```html
Private Sub btnAdd_Click()
  Dim db As Database
  Dim Computer As Recordset
  Dim CompHDD As Recordset
  Dim HDD As Recordset

  Set db = CurrentDb
  Set Computer = db.OpenRecordset("Select * from [tblComputer]")
  Set CompHDD = db.OpenRecordset("Select * from [tblComputer-HDD]")
  Set HDD = db.OpenRecordset("Select * from [tblHDD]")

  If Computer.NoMatch = True Then
    Computer.AddNew
    Computer("Computer") = Me.txtComputer
    Computer.Update

  ElseIf HDD.NoMatch = True Then
    HDD.AddNew
    HDD("HDD") = Me.txtHDD
    HDD.Update

  Else
    CompHDD.AddNew
    CompHDD("Computer") = Me.txtComputer
    CompHDD("HDD") = Me.txtHDD
    CompHDD.Update
  End If

  txtComputer.Value = ""
  txtHDD.Value = ""

  Set Computer = Nothing
  Set CompHDD = Nothing
  Set HDD = Nothing
  Set db = Nothing
End Sub
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you put a primary key on all three tables, then you can simply append the values. The PK will prevent duplicates from being added.

I would use the following to add a computer and HDD pair to the tblComputer-HDD table. You should be able to change up the syntax to handle the other two table appends from this example.

```
DoCmd.SetWarnings False
DoCmd.Execute "INSERT INTO [tblComputer-HDD] ([Computer], [HDD]) VALUES ('" & Me.txtComputer & "', '" & Me.txtHDD & "')"
'Other Code
DoCmd.SetWarnings True
```

Comment: I'm a little bit confuse. So for tblComputer my PK is Computer and for tblHDD my PK is HDD. So what you are saying is that I should removed the composite keys on tblComputer-HDD and create its own PK right?

Comment: Thank you! I figured out what you were trying to say! Also, after I click the button, it keeps giving me a message saying "You are about to append 1 row(s). Once you click Yes, you can't use the Undo command to reverse the changes. Are you sure you want to append the selected rows?" Am I able to remove this?

Comment: Update the answer to disable those prompts.